# OAuth to WCF service

Tags: android, wcf, oauth, openid, accountmanager

Im building an Android application which consumes a WCF-application.
In the application I dont want any login at all. But on the WCF-service I want to authenticate and authorize the user that tries to consume the service.

My idea is this:

- Somehow get an oauth-token from the Android phone (for example using Accountmanager and the phone users google account)
- Send the token to the WCF and somehow make sure its valid? And then proceding with the call.

Is this even possible? 
Do you have suggestions on which frameworks I should use? Both for Android and .NET.